# Django cannot find libmysqlclient after upgrade MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5

Tags: python, django, mysql5.5

I have a Server with `Debian 6 squeeze`. 
I've made some upgrade to `Debian 7 wheezy`. 
`MySQL` is upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5.

Now I have an application developed with Django, and it got me an error, `cannot find libmysqlclient.so.15`; I have `libmysqlclient.so.16`.

I've tried to make some symbolic link into `/usr/lib` of `libmysqlclient.so.16` and `libmysqlclient_r.so.16` to `libmysqlclient.so.15` and `libmysqlclient_r.so.16`. Now I got this another error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.15: version `libmysqlclient_15' not found
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: ... Update MySQLdb...

Comment: Thanks, how can I do that? What is MySQLdb? a Python library? a Linux Library? a DJango Library? Sorry for my idiot questions...

Comment: Do you have `mysql-python` installed? Run `pip list --format=freeze | grep -i mysql` and add the output to the question.

Comment: If you are developing with Python 3, replace `pip` with `pip3` in the above command.